# Not recalling variable value

Tags: vba, excel

I typically consider myself a super-user for excel-vba related things.  However, this one has me stumped.

I have a line of code returning 'runtime-9, subscript out of range', but it appears that the subscript is not out of range.

When the following code is evaluated, it returns the subscript error.

```
Range(Cells(RowArray(j, 0), coLs(colSetNum, i)), Cells(RowArray(j, 1), coLs(colSetNum, i))).Select
```

Where RowArray(j,0)=2, colSetNum=0, i=0, and RowArray(j,1)=6.  (all values from the mouse-over text).

I checked the locals window, and coLs(0)(0)=2, so it shouldn't be returning this error.

Any suggestions?

Comment: so is `coLs` an array of arrays or is it a two dimensional array, you show it both ways.  Maybe you should use `coLs(colSetNum)(i)`

Comment: coLs is an array of arrays.  Do I have to reference that as (0)(0) rather than (0,0)?

Comment: Yes, and also one should avoid using `.Select`.  It slows down the code.

Comment: Ah, that did it!  my next line is selection.copy.  I tried just doing Range().copy, but it didn't seem to like that.  What alternatives are there?

Comment: there are many.  it also depends on how you are pasting the copy.  But that is a new question.

Comment: Also, don't use naked `Range()` and `Cells()` objects as they imply  `ActiveWorksheet` which might not be the intended behavior. Always qualify statements with a worksheet, as in `Sheets("input").Range("B2").Cells(10,1).Resize(1,16)` for example.

Comment: I am selecting the sheet in the line directly above the range, so I'm not worried bout the naked `range()` and `cells()` callouts.  But I will remember that for future.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays of Arrays have to be referenced as arr(x)(y), rather than arr(x,y).

Fixing this fixed the program.